# Warning when nullable int is involved in an arithmetic operation

Tags: c#, code-analysis

The following code doesn't produce any warning or error:

```
int? test1 = null;
var test2 = test1 + 123;
test1++;
var test3 = test1;
```

`test2` and `test3` end up being `null`.  I find this rather unintuitive and risky behaviour because I'd have assumed that, being null in such an operation, `test1` would've been assigned its default value of zero, causing `test2` and `test3` to be 123, and 1.

Is there a way I can get a code analysis warning when a nullable int is involved in an arithmetic operation without first being null-coalesced to an actual integer?

Comment: A helpful blog [posts](https://ericlippert.com/2015/08/31/nullable-comparisons-are-weird/) (maybe)

Comment: _"is there a way I can get a code analysis warning when a nullable int is involved"_ - I agree that would be useful for some people, but other people (such as myself) would find those warnings unhelpful and noisy - so why not just _not_ use nullable types in arithmetic code entirely?

Comment: _"Is there a way I can get a code analysis warning"_ - by writing an analyzer yourself!

Comment: The semantics of nullable value types deliberately imitate database `NULL` logic for lifted operators (except for equality checks, because that would break too many other things) because providing storage for such values was a major motivation for their creation. Having a warning for what is for all intents and purposes the way the language was designed would not be helpful -- at least not out of the box. A custom analyzer would be the way to go here if you find yourself writing this pattern unintentionally.

Comment: If you explicitly state that `test2` and `test3` should be `int` instead of `var` then you should see warnings. Why do you expect warnings when you use `var`? (which usefully assumes `int?`)

Comment: @JeroenMostert You realize you can suppress warnings that you don't want?

Comment: Of course -- but it would be counterproductive for the compiler to issue warnings about behavior that was *by design*, especially since C# tends to be good at only issuing relevant warnings (to the point were turning on "warnings as errors" is usually helpful without having to suppress much, if anything). You could argue the *design* needed to be fixed, but that ship has sailed.

Comment: The design sucks.  :-)  That said, maybe something like StyleCop could still issue a warning for it because that doesn't always refrain from warning about language features that are by design, but potentially problematic.

Comment: As others have commented, a custom analyzer could certainly do this (the StyleCop rules use the same framework). It's just not present out of the box. You could also consider not using `int?` if you dislike its semantics, and use your own `Option<int>` struct with the desired semantics for conversion and operators. `int?` is just `Nullable<int>` with slight magic for boxing and unboxing (that you can probably do without).

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour that you have described as problematic is the intended behaviour for nullable types.

In what scenario would you want an null integer to be given a value of 0 rather than remain null?

It seems like it would be better to use a normal `int` with a default value for your scenario.

```
int test1 = default;
var test2 = test1 + 123;
test1++;
var test3 = test1;
```

You could also add handling to methods dealing with nullable integers but it seems more like you simply shouldn't be using them for your scenario.

Short of writing a custom code analyser ([Write Custom Code Analyser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix)), I don't think you can achieve the warnings you want.

Comment: Well I have a game board with hexes that store some meta info that may sometimes be null and may sometimes not be.  On some events, I want to increment a hex's value, and if it's null I want treat its initial value as 0.  Yeah, I can explicitly do that, but I'm finding it quite easy to forget that it doesn't just default to zero in such an operation and so it could result in silent bugs in my code.

Comment: Might be worth updating the question with more context, that would help us to provide a more satisfactory solution but I get the impression that a custom data type would help solve your issue.